# How to get the expiration timestamp of a session?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.JS and Express web framework, I need to work with Sessions.

I would get the expiration timestamp of the session, is this possible?

I would like to know when(timestamp format) the session expires.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [Connect docs, session middleware page](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html) (Express uses Connect internally):

> Session#maxAge
>
> Alternatively req.session.cookie.maxAge will return the time remaining
>   in milliseconds, which we may also re-assign a new value to adjust the
>   .expires property appropriately. The following are essentially
>   equivalent

So `req.session.cookie.maxAge` is what you're looking for.